# How can I run docker on a Windows VM on Linux

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, docker, docker-for-windows

Here is my situation: I'm working on a linux machine (Linux Mint 18.2) doing work with .NET Core. One particular project needs to use .NET Framework, so I spun up a Windows 10 virtual machine with VirtualBox. Now I need to package this application into a docker container. I've tried to install docker on the Windows VM, but always get an error when starting the daemon, and get this error when running docker build:

```
error during connect: Post 
open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
```

My question is, is this even possible? Is there some configuration that will get docker running on a Windows VM, or do I need to be on a standalone system?

Comment: The error suggests it needs to be  "run as admin" so, likely to be unrelated with the VM.

Comment: Do you have [nested virtualization enabled](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_enable_nested_virtualization_in_KVM#Nested_virt_support)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always I figured it out right after I posted this. Docker on Windows defaults to using Linux containers which caused the error. After switching to Windows containers everything worked fine.